# Recording issuing service and user with events in CQRS/ES system

Tags: typescript, authorization, cqrs, audit, event-sourcing

Say I have the classic customer bounded context and a `MakeCustomerPreferred` command and that I have some cross cutting concerns such as logging and authorization. Although the way to handle these cross cutting concerns have been discussed extensively I'm curious about the case where we wish to record information about the user or the service that was responsible for issuing the command in the domain events themselves.

Example event:

```
interface CustomerMadePreferred {
    customerId: string,
    issuingService: string,
    issuingUser: string,
}
```

Example command:

```
interface MakeCustomerPreferred {
    customerId: string
}
```

Using the command above we would lack the context that details the issuing user and service. We could require the client to supply values for `issuingService` and `issuingUser` as part of the command but the problem is that typically the command as submitted by the client and lets assume for this case that the client is a web browser outside of the control of the application where we cannot control which values the user may submit within the command. Additionally we can determine these values in general if our service is behind a ReSTful or JSON Web API by using things like OAuth tokens. This leaves me with a few obvious strategies.

Possible Strategies:

1. Include `issuingService` and `issuingUser` with the command and then validate them against values determined from auth context. This allows the command as issued by the client to be identical to the one processed by the handler and keeps the handler implementation simple in that it only needs a command parameter and no auth context passed in.
2. Extract `issuingService` and `issuingUser` from auth context and added/injected those details to the command handed over to the command handler. This makes it easier on the clients issuing the original command but the contract of the command is slightly different between the command handler and and the client. Example: `Object.assign({}, makeCustomerPreferredCommand, authContext);`
3. Pass the auth context as a separate argument to the command handler or make it available from a service that can be called by the command handler. This preserves the contract of the command but complicates the command handler implementation.

I'm leaning towards options **1** and **2** mainly because it seems to allow for a functional approach to the command handler implementation. Perhaps I'm leaving out some option or overlooking some details which may render including `issuingService` and `issuingUser` in the events unnecessary.

**UPDATE:** An alternative, lets call it option **4**, could be to not include these details in the generated *CustomerMadePreferred* event and instead handle and emit separate `CommandIssued` events that could contain a key of some sort that could be used to relate issuer information with events emitted by the command handler.

Comment: As per technical implementation, when I am thinking about the same issue, my plan is to add some metadata to the event. So the event will remain a domain object but I can attach some technical metadata to it to identify the context.

Comment: @jpierson there's no difference between 2. and 3. as far as *the command is slightly different between the command handler and and the client*, is there ?

Comment: @guillaume31, the differences between 2 and 3 are subtle perhaps but in terms of how one may go about writing unit testing around these or any other reflective tooling around the command types would be affected a great deal. The contract of the command handler classes/functions would also be impacted between.

Answer (score 1):

I almost like option 4 -- my feeling is that correlation ID is the wrong mechanism.  Instead, I would use a causation ID; correlation ID means something slightly different.  All of the events generated by command.id:N would have event.causationId:N, and you could go back to the command history (outside of the domain) to check any concerns outside the domain.

That said, you probably need to be looking at *who* wants to capture this information.  If it's your devOps team, then keeping the domain events clean is probably the right choice, just link to the command history as described above.

But if your domain experts are the ones that want this, that should raise eyebrows, because it is suggesting that there are domain concepts hiding here that need to be teased out of the ubiquitous language and incorporated into your model.

(Compare with [Don't Create Aggregate Roots](http://udidahan.com/2009/06/29/dont-create-aggregate-roots/); changes to the customer account don't come from nothing.  Are they really coming from within the domain?  If so, then that probably wants to be tracked.)

Comment: Great points! I like the term causationId, I've also heard the phrase _originating command_ used to describe the concept of associating events to a given command too. In my case I think the question of how to or whether to include such information on events is more of a _developer_ or _operational_ concern than a concern directly by the domain experts indicating that option 4 may be the better fit if at all at this stage.

Answer (score 1):

I usually end up reaching for the authentication context directly in the command handler as a least-complicated solution (which I'm not sure if it matches 2. or 3. in your case). The command structure being different between client and server isn't an issue in my case, since the client doesn't send commands per se, I represent it through (HTTP resource, verb, content type).

Comment: I was thinking about this too. I guess it depends on how much the command contract is exposed to the client and whether it's following a more RPC style limited to GET/POST or utilizing the HTTP facilities as you mention.